# Manipular um item por vez na API

Tags: c#, api

Eu tenho uma **API** que faz o **POST** de *Item* no banco de dados, mas antes de fazer o POST ela faz um **GET** para obter um código para o *Item* que vai ser salvo.

OBS: este código não pode se repetir no banco de dados, tem que ser único.

Ao mandar uma array com dois itens, eles estão pegando o mesmo código, dando conflito na hora de gravar no DB.

Imagem: **POST** sendo debugado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dois itens passam na linha 102, e depois os dois itens passam na linha 113.

Como fazer para que um item por vez obtenha o código e depois salve no banco para então os próximos itens fazerem o mesmo processo?

Comment: você já tentou fazer um foreach quando tem-se mais de 01 item ? Assim você irá gravar um item por vez e obter um novo código para o item a cada iteração.

Comment: Eu ja tenho um FOR na aplicação que manda item por item para a API.

Comment: posta o código dessa parte aí. :)

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.itemObj.length; i++) {
 Prevendas.incluirItemPreVenda($rootScope.itemObj[i]).success(function () {
  console.log("incluirItemPreVenda OK");
 }).error(function () {
  console.log("incluirItemPreVenda Erro");
 })
}`

Comment: Isso esta acontecendo por que você esta fazendo várias chamadas assíncronas, qual banco de dados você esta utilizando? Não existe a possibilidade de colocar este campo como identitiy/autoincrement?

Comment: Qual banco de dados você usa?

Comment: Banco de dados dbc, mas não posso usar o autoincrement porque não posso alterar o banco porque o mesmo esta usado por outro sistema desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi controlar o envio de itens para a API, enviando um item por vez, porque a API não tem controle sobre quantos itens estão sendo salvos.
Segue código que faz o POST na API e manda item somente quando o anterior já foi salvo.

```
//  Faz a inclusão do objeto de itemObj no banco de dados.
function incluirItensFunc(tnNrItem) {
    //  Atribui o cdprevenda ao itemObj[].
    $rootScope.itemObj[tnNrItem].Cdprevenda = $rootScope.prevendaSelecionado;
    if (tnNrItem == ($rootScope.itemObj.length - 1)) {
        Prevendas.incluirItemPreVenda($rootScope.itemObj[tnNrItem]).success(function () {
            console.log("incluirItemPreVenda OK");
            $rootScope.itemObj = [];
            calcularTotalPreVendaFunc();
        }).error(function () {
            console.log("incluirItemPreVenda Erro");
        })
    }
    else {
        Prevendas.incluirItemPreVenda($rootScope.itemObj[tnNrItem]).success(function () {
            console.log("incluirItemPreVenda OK");
            //  Chama a função incluirItensFunc novamente passando tnNrItem + 1 como parâmetro.
            incluirItensFunc(tnNrItem + 1);
        }).error(function () {
            console.log("incluirItemPreVenda Erro");
        })
    }
}
```